# Implement Adjustable and dismissable column in my webpage

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am implementing a project dashboard where I have 3 adjustable columns when they are opened together they share the screen width and I can close 1 or more than 1 panel(column) then the rest of the column will adjust to share the spaces, here is a working demo->

[image]

The site is https://www.pivotaltracker.com  , HOw do I obtain this functionality , as  so far I have only know bootstrap grid columns, but how to make such a dynamic adjustment?(which is not possible with simple bootstrap grid) -as I also want that close panel and open panel functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding bootstrap, I think you can provide each div with a class of col just, so the available space will divide into the existing div.

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col">col1</div>
 <div class="col">col2</div>
</div>
```

or with pure CSS ( especillay flexbox ) you can apply flex-grow:1; to each child div,

```
<div class="contaier">
 <div>box1</div>
 <div>box2</div>
</div>
```

```
.container {
 display:flex;
}
.contaier div {
 flex-grow: 1;
}
```